# Basic Center Aligning with CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net

My apologies for how basic this question is but I'm in the early stages of trying to learn ASP.NET, having had a largely WinForms background.

I am creating a Master Page with a Menu Bar on it and am failing to even get the Menu to center on the page.

My mark up is as follows -

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Page Title</title>   
<link href="CSS/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="HomeForm" runat="server">
<div id="MainDiv">
    <asp:Panel ID="HeaderPanel" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
        <header>
            <img src="/Artwork/Webhead.jpg" />
        </header>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div id="MenuDiv">
        <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False"></asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
    </div>    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is as follows -

```
*
{
font-family: Calibri
}

#MainDiv
{
margin: auto;
background-color: cyan;
}

#HeaderPanel
{

}

#MenuDiv
{
margin: auto;
}

#MainMenu
{
margin: auto;
background-color: yellow;
align-self: center;
}
```

The logo in the  section centers ok, but the Menu doesn't.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
#MainMenu{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```